# It shows "required initializer init must be provided in subclass of UIControl" When I override init(frame: CGRect)

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, overriding, initializer

This code works:

```
import UIKit

class wheel: UIControl {

}
```

But this code doesn't:

```
class wheel: UIControl {
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}
```

It shows error "*required initializer init must be provided in **subclass** of `UIControl`*" when I override init(frame: CGRect) but not `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`.

Why do I have to implement `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`? And why don't I need to implement it if I didn't implement `init(frame: CGRect)`?

I found a similar Stack Overflow post but it didn't explain:
[Swift : Error: 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UIView'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35255466/swift-error-required-initializer-initcoder-must-be-provided-by-subclas)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Look. According to [Apple documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) Swift subclasses do not inherit their superclass initializers by default. They are inherited only in certain circumstances, one of which is: If your subclass doesn’t define any designated initializers, it automatically inherits all of its superclass designated initializers. So if you're not implementing `init(frame: CGRect)` all super initializers are inherited.

Also UIView adopts NSCoding protocol, which requires an `init(coder:)` initializer. So if you're implementing `init(frame: CGRect)`, your class is no longer inheriting super initializers. So you must implement that one too:

```
required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init?(coder: decoder)
}
```

Comment: Good answer. But the code example should say `required init?` instead of `init`.

Comment: Please add the comment about `convenience` keyword from the answer below. That will make your answer complete and even more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When creating your model Object subclasses, you may sometimes want to add your own custom initialization methods for added convenience.

Due to some present limitations with Swift introspection, these methods cannot be designated initializers for the class. Instead, they need to be marked as convenience initializers using the Swift keyword of the same name [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHCcp.png)